# Does INTERSECT operator exist in the SQL standard?

Tags: sql, intersect, ansi-sql

Does INTERSECT operator exist in the SQL standard? 
If it exists, is it an optional operator?

Please, leave a trustable source.

Comment: What should an *intersect* operator do?

Comment: Why are you asking?  I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes", but that has little bearing on whether or not databases support it.

Comment: Hello,if wikipedia is trustable for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)

Comment: @wallyk This operator intersect the result of two queries.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#INTERSECT_operator as GordonLinoff sent. But Wikipedia is not trustable for me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am asking because my professor said the SQL standard does not support it. But I cannot believe because many DBMS that use SQL support intersection.

Comment: @zip this is not trustable enough. But I know that such an operator exists in many SQL languages

Comment: For the first few decades, we had only genuine SQL platforms, thank Codd.  They were not called SQL unless they complied with the SQL Standard.
In the 00's with freeware; shareware; vapourware; noware becoming accepted for non-commercial use, there were various suites of code, which were neither platforms (no Server Architecture; no ACID Transactions; etc) nor SQL (no compliance).  But they have "SQL" in their name, which is **fraud**.
Most lecturers like their freeware **NON**sql, erroneously think that it is SQL, and then make false claims about SQL from that place of ignorance.

Comment: The SQL 99 Validator (https://developer.mimer.com/services/sql-validator-99/) says: _Validation result: The following feature outside Core SQL-99 is used:
F302, "INTERSECT table operator"_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your professor is either wrong, or else you misunderstood what they said. INTERSECT is not supported in every *implementation* of SQL, but it is the standard.

I checked my copy of ["Understanding the New SQL: A Complete Guide" by Jim Melton and Alan R. Simon (1993)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558602453) which covers SQL-92.

Page 171 says:

> **The INTERSECT and EXCEPT Operators**
>
> INTERSECT returns all rows that exist in the intersection of two tables; that is, in both tables.
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
>   FROM music_titles
> INTERSECT
> SELECT * 
>   FROM discontinued_albums;
> ```
>
> The preceding query will return, for example, all discontinued albums that have been re-released.

Here's a link to Google Books with the word INTERSECT highlighted in a search: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Understanding_the_New_SQL/ZOOMSTZ4T_QC?bsq=intersect&gbpv=1

I also checked my copy of ["SQL-99 Complete, Really" by Peter Gulutzan and Trudy Pelzer (1999)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879305681). It also documents INTERSECT.

Answer (score 2):

`INTERSECT` is included in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard (*ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E)*), as the *optional* feature F302:

```
F302 INTERSECT table operator

F302-01 INTERSECT DISTINCT table operator
F302-02 INTERSECT ALL table operator
```